# Optimal Database design regarding functionality of letting user share posts by other users

Tags: postgresql, database-design, left-join

I want to implement functionality which let user share posts by other users similar to what Facebook and Google+ share button and twitter retweet.

There are 2 choices:

1) I create duplicate copy of the post and have a column which keeps track of the original post id and makes clear this is a shared post.

2) I have a separate table shared post where I save the post id which is a foreign key to post id in post table.

Talking in terms of programming basically I keep pointer to the original post in a separate table and when need to get post posted by user and also shared ones I do a left join on post and shared post table

```
    Post(post_id(PK), post_content, posted_by)

    SharedPost(post_id(FK to Post.post_id), sharing_user, sharedfrom(in case someone shares from non owners profile))
```

I am in favour of second choice but wanted to know the advice of experts out there?

One thing more posts on my webapp will be more on the lines of facebook size not tweet size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that your system would do one of the two:
Put code inline for the post (similar to a hyperlink) that would reference the original post.  I do not know if you are trying to pull in images or other media.  When you encounter this inline code, your system could either create a hyperlink to view the original or pull data from the original into the post that is sharing it.

Alternatively your `posts`table could have a column for `shared_post` that could either be a `post_id` or a hyperlink to an external item to share.  Your system can then recognize that if the value is `null` or `-1` that it is not a shared post and can treat it normally.

I would not recommend creating a new table for storing duplicates of the shared posts.  It becomes harder to maintain and update.

Additionally, if you plan on having sharing groups involved in this system, you will most likely need another table that links `post_id` to `sharing_group_id`.

Comment: so you are saying that I create a new post and in post content add some hyperlink to original post and when this link comes into play then show original content to which this link is pointing. Right?

Comment: That is one option.  The other is that the link would have to be used (followed/clicked) to go to a prepared view of the original post.

Comment: Would not that take an extra db query when user follows the link? Whereas bringing original post content would take a self join.

Comment: That is correct.  It is all just up to what requirements you have.  Just trying to let you know some design options.